# TensorFlow Error: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients

Tags: python, tensorflow, backpropagation, mnist

Trying to use Derived class of Tensorflow **FIFOQueue**. I override the enqueue function. It takes in the images and enqueues the output from the final dense layer, in the queue.
Now I dequeue the output tensor and try to calculate Cost function and minimize it using Adam Optimiser.

On calculating cost and minimizing it inside the enqueue function itself, my code works fine. But as soon as I shift the loss_op (i.e my cost) outside the Derived class, I get the error: "No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients"

## Import

```
from tensorflow.python.ops.data_flow_ops import FIFOQueue
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes as _dtypes
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import gen_data_flow_ops
```

## Read the data

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

n_input = 784 # MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)
n_classes = 10 # MNIST total classes (0-9 digits)
Y = mnist.train.labels
X = mnist.train.images
```

## Derived Queue

```
class MyQueue(FIFOQueue):
    def enqueue(self, x,Y,name=None):
    
        #Reshape
        x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])
        # 1st conv_2d layer
        conv1_mp = tf.layers.conv2d(x, 32, 5, activation=tf.nn.relu,name = 'Q1_c1')
        # 1st max pool layer
        conv1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv1_mp, 2, 2,name='Q1_mp1')
        # 2nd conv_2d layer
        conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv1, 64, 3, activation=tf.nn.relu,name = 'Q1_c2')
        # 2nd max pool layer
        conv2_mp = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv2, 2, 2,name='Q1_mp2')
        #Flatten
        flat = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(conv2_mp)                
        #Dense 1
        dense_1 = tf.layers.dense(tf.reshape(flat,[-1,1600]), 1024,name = 'Q2_D1' )
        #Dropout = 0.8
        drop = tf.layers.dropout(dense_1, rate=0.8, training=True,name='Q2_Dp')
        #Output class = 10
        out = tf.layers.dense(drop, n_classes,name = 'Q2_Op')      
        
        
        #update vals to put "out" in the queue
        vals = out
        
        
        # Rest of the enqueue operation which has not been changed
        
        with ops.name_scope(name, "%s_enqueue" % self._name,
                        self._scope_vals(vals)) as scope:
              vals = self._check_enqueue_dtypes(vals)
              # NOTE(mrry): Not using a shape function because
              #  we need access to the `QueueBase` object.
              for val, shape in zip(vals, self._shapes):
                val.get_shape().assert_is_compatible_with(shape)
        
              if self._queue_ref.dtype == _dtypes.resource:
                return gen_data_flow_ops.queue_enqueue_v2(
                    self._queue_ref, vals, name=scope)
              else:
                return gen_data_flow_ops.queue_enqueue(
                    self._queue_ref, vals, name=scope)
```

## Main

```
q_pred = MyQueue( capacity=1, dtypes=tf.float32 )
enqueue_op = q_pred.enqueue(X,Y)
data_pred = q_pred.dequeue()

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(init)
   sess.run(enqueue_op)  

   out = data_pred


   #Calculating Cost
   cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
            logits=out, labels=Y),name = 'Q2_loss')

   # Adam optimiser
   optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)

   #Write in the graph
   writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("logs\MyDerivedQueue", sess.graph)

   ####### ERROR LINE ###################
   # Minimising the cost. 
   train_op = optimizer.minimize(cost)

   correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(out, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
   accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple hit and trial methods. I came to the conclusion that this won't work as backpropagation isn't in our control. While using multi GPU, every GPU will give it's feedforward and now while back propagating, we won't get to know which weights/parameters should be updated.